# Objective function of a Genetic Algorithm

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm, fitness, objective-function

This is my first effort about AI/ML.

I have the following problem given by my teacher,

> Design a simple genetic algorithm in MATLAB, with binary-coded chromosomes, in
>   order to solve pattern finding problem in 16-bit strings.
>
> The objective function is given by the following formula:
>
> `F(x) =`
>   `NoS("010") + 2NoS("0110") + 3NoS("01110") + 4NoS("011110") +` 
>   `5NoS("0111110") + 6NoS("01111110") + 7NoS("011111110") +`
>   `6NoS("0111111110") +  5NoS("01111111110") + 4NoS("011111111110") +`
>   `3NoS("0111111111110") +  2NoS("01111111111110") +`
>   `NoS("011111111111110")`

I couldn't understand the formula.

What does it mean by Nos?

**What operations are they performing on those binary strings?**

What is `F(x)`?

Comment: Nos is probably: nitric oxide synthase

Comment: @marcan2020, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can read, the NoS are Nitric oxide synthase like [NoS1](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P29475)  or [NoS2](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P35228). They are some genes of different species.

These are probably referring to minimize functions: https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/examples/coding-and-minimizing-a-fitness-function-using-the-genetic-algorithm.html

I hope I'm helping.

Comment: What operations are they performing on those binary strings?